# Why AS3 toFixed method returns a String?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Is there any (rational) reason why the [toFixed method](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Number.html#toFixed%28%29) of AS3 Number class returns a String?

Comment: Rational decisions in AS3? That's a good one.

Comment: That's exactly the point of the method (to have a String representation of a Number, like for instance "4.00"). Whatever else would you use it for?

Comment: @RIAstar: well, to reduce the number of decimals without performing a multiplication...

Comment: There's Math.round() for that. `Math.round(1.1234 * 100) / 100)` will yield 1.12

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice you wrote **without** multiplication. Eh well, you could write your own convenience method to eliminate that step.

Comment: You could just cast it back: `Number(Number(7.13143).toFixed(3));`

Comment: @RIAstar.  there is that, but the Number methods (`toFixed()`, etc.) don't use that since they return string objects.  the question is why do they return strings and not numbers?  is it because of a performance gain or is it an oversight?

Comment: Because their purpose is to give you a humanly readable representation of a floating point Number to display in a table for instance. Their purpose is not to round.

Comment: @RIAstar you should post that as an answer.

Comment: Not that it matters much but for the record, it's part of the ECMAScript specs and works the same way in JavaScript. http://qfox.nl/ecma/341

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The purpose of the `toFixed` and other such convenience methods on the Number class is to give you a humanly readable String representation of that Number. Its purpose is not to round it, as you seem to assume. There's `Math.round()` for real rounding operations.

An obvious use case would be a table or a spreadsheet where you would want all your numbers to be displayed in the same way (e.g. 1.25 - 6.10). That would make it easier for humans to scan the data and doesn't change the underlying Number (which in the example could be: 1.2567 - 6.1).

Comment: The fact is the AS3 quantity of decimals is very often unnecessary: I generally need a maximum of 2 or 3 decimals. I hoped there would be some native method to truncate number before performing calculations. Anyway Math.round (Math.round alone) is not enough.

Comment: To round to 2 decimal places try this: Math.round(5.9367 * 100) / 100. To change the number of decimals you want simply adjust the factor.

Comment: Hey, cmann, this is quite easy, but it wasn't this the point. Check my first comment to read what I simply hoped.